# Reduce nested JSON using generic TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I have the following JSON.

```
{"results":
  {"data": {
    "id":"93cba9bd-2969-3214-b26f-7f42d20241a4",
    "first_name":"PSU",
    "last_name":"Bot",
    "profile": {
        "data":{"about":"i am so happy",}
     }
  }
}
```

Now when I get the data back from the API. I want to deserialize it so that a model with the following definition:

```
export class Person extends BaseModel {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    profile: DataType<Profile>;
}
```

Would have it's *profile* property without the data element.

How can I construct a generic DataType so that I can achieve this? Here is what I have so far.

```
export class DataType<T> {

public constructor(arg: T) {
    console.log(arg);
    return new arg.data;
  }
}
```

Also, is this a generic type territory or an object (class) as in the example above?

Comment: Do you have the definition for type/interface `Profile` somewhere in your code? It is unclear what the purpose of the `DataType` class is. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: The data type is to encapsulate responses that conform to the same nested structure that is they are nested under a data namespace within an object

Answer (score 0):

Regarding nested logic you can do.

```
export class DataType<T> {
  public constructor(public data: T) {}
}
```

Or delegate it like so.

```
export class DataType<T> {
  public data: T;

  public constructor(obj: {"data":T}) {
    this.data = obj.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would this make it so that the json would ned up like:

    `{"results":
  {"data": {
    "id":"93cba9bd-2969-3214-b26f-7f42d20241a4",
    "first_name":"PSU",
    "last_name":"Bot",
    "profile": {
        "about":"i am so happy"
     }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know for sure your `profile` property or any other value that replaces it will have the `data` property, you can define the following generic class for modeling that part of the response:

```
export class DataType<T extends { data: any }> {
    public data: any;

    public constructor(arg: T) {
        this.data = arg.data;
    }

    public toJSON(): any {
        return {
            data: this.data,
        };
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `toJSON` method is not required, but useful if you call `JSON.stringify` on this or the enclosing object. Using this method you can manipulate the output as you wish.